# HttpClient getting status codes and follow redirects to get end page status code

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm going mad trying to get HttpClient to work the way I want it. It's all going over my head.

All I want to do is provide a URL, the URL could point to web pages, .zip files, .doc files and redirects that end up at any of the above. I would then be able to print the final status code to the console.

Can anyone please help me out here? So far I have(a mess of code after throwing everything at it):

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    client.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy(){
        public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)  {
            boolean isRedirect=false;
            try {
                isRedirect = super.isRedirected(request, response, context );
            } catch (org.apache.http.ProtocolException e) {
                System.out.println("what?");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!isRedirect) {
                int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                System.out.println(responseCode);
                if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) {
                    System.out.println("redirect");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return isRedirect;
        }
    });

    HttpHead test = new HttpHead("http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/troubleshoot/game-play");
    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(test);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("400");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("404");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

EDIT:

For this url: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/troubleshoot/game-play I'm getting 404. I would have expected 200.

For http://www.google.com I get a 200 as expected.

For http://tinyurl.com/2tx a tinyurl redirect to google.com I get a 200.

I'm not sure what to make of my results. I just want to be able to test links to see if they are working or broken from an end users point of view.

Comment: It would be useful to tell us what the code above is outputting, and what the undesired behavior is that you are seeing.

Comment: Also, the status codes should not necessarily be hard-coded. Use `HttpStatus` constants for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are sending a HEAD request instead of a GET request, for which the xbox site just return a 404.

Using:

```
HttpGet test = new HttpGet("http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/troubleshoot/game-play");
```

without any redirect stuff just works fine for me.

Comment: But if I try to use this to get the status of a link to a large .zip file will it not try to download the file before returning it's status to me?

Comment: Status code will be in the header of the response so, as long as you don't try to read the content of the request, httpclient will not read it. Remember that you can always see the exchange between the client and server just configuring the httpclient logging to debug level.